# Can scrapyRT run in parallel on Heroku using gunicorn?

Tags: heroku, scrapy, twisted, gunicorn, wsgi

So far, I have been able to run my scrapyRT project on Heroku (cloud platform). Next step is running scrapyRT in parallel on a Heroku's single node (1 dyno), as I want to use my computational resources effectively.

One option is using gunicorn, as it is able to run various WSGI HTTP servers in parallel. Unfortunately, scrapyRT is based on Twisted and it does not support WSGI natively. As far as I know, twisted can serve WSGI applications (please check
https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.0.0/web/howto/web-in-60/wsgi.html), but I would like to know if following this website is a good idea for adapting scrapyRT in a WSGI application or I can find some design restriction.

Comment: Wrapping scrapyRT in a WSGI app is pointless. Can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do in parallel? Do you need multiple scrapyRT serving different projects?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I would like to know if there is some way to improve the performance of my application based on scrapyRT and crawlera (in Heroku), when there ara several requests at the same time

Comment: "performance" is a vague term that makes it hard give you a specific answer. Twisted can already handle multiple requests concurrently. Is it not enough? How many requests are you trying to handle at peak load? A more important question, why are you hitting a scrapyRT with any kind of load? Seems odd

Comment: Please, let me improve my explanation.
1) All requests are sent one by one to the scrapyRT HTTP server running in one Heroku dyno. These requests are processed by scrapyRT activating the desired spider. 
2) The spider launches the HTTP requests with the Crawlera server in order to obtain the HTML file.
3) Once Crawlera returns the HTML file to the spider, this is parsed and returned as an item.
4) Finally scrapyRT sends the item to the initial client.
Currently, scrapyRT is only facing 1-2 requests per second, but it will increase. What is the proper way to parallelize this process?